# Prevent class and enum merging in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, conditional-compilation

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#ifdef SECTION_A
class MyClass
{
    float memberA;
};
#endif

#ifdef SECTION_B
class MyClass
{
    float memberB;
};
#endif
```

In real life, `SECTION_A` and `SECTION_B` will never be defined simultaneously.  However, when I generate my Doxygen documentation, I define both sections, so Doxygen generates a single documentation for my product.

The resulting output in Doxygen is:

```
class MyClass
{
    float memberA;
    float memberB;
};
```

In Doxygen, is there a way to prevent merging of classes and enums, in order to get separate definitions for each of the types defined in different `#ifdef` sections?

Comment: I can't help but wonder why redefine `MyClass` inside each `#ifdef`. Why not just conditionally define the members?

Comment: they are actually defined in separate files.

Comment: @decasteljau Did you find a way around this?